# Get leading whitespace

Tags: c#, string, .net-4.0, whitespace

I just wrote this method and I'm wondering if something similar already exists in the framework? It just seems like one of those methods...

If not, is there a better way to do it?

```
/// <summary>
/// Return the whitespace at the start of a line.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="trimToLowerTab">Round the number of spaces down to the nearest multiple of 4.</param>
public string GetLeadingWhitespace(string line, bool trimToLowerTab = true)
{
    int whitespace = 0;
    foreach (char ch in line)
    {
        if (ch != ' ') break;
        ++whitespace;
    }

    if (trimToLowerTab)
        whitespace -= whitespace % 4;

    return "".PadLeft(whitespace);
}
```

Thanks

**Edit:** 
after reading some comments, Its clear that I also need to handle tabs.

I can't give a very good example because the website trims spaces down to just one but I'll try:

Say the input is a string with 5 spaces, the method will return a string with 4 spaces. If the input is less than 4 spaces, it returns `""`. 
This might help:

```
input spaces | output spaces
0 | 0
1 | 0
2 | 0
3 | 0
4 | 4
5 | 4
6 | 4
7 | 4
8 | 8
9 | 8
...
```

Comment: Can you give some sample input/output?  It's not completely clear what you're trying to do from your code.  For example, if the first char is not whitespace and `trimToLowerTab == false`, then `whitespace == 0`.  Therefore you always end up with `return "".PadLeft(0)`, no matter the length of the line.  If the second char is not whitespace, you always end up with 1 space, and so forth.  I'm not seeing where the rounding is done in these cases.  A bit more context would help too.

Comment: So if I give the string `" e"` (imagine 3 spaces), the returned string from the method should be "" because there were only 3 spaces. But if the input string was `" e"` (5 spaces), the returned string will be `" "`(4spaces) (the nearest multiple of 4 below the total number of spaces). If the argument is false, then leading spaces are just given without any modification. Edit: the website strips out whitespace from the comments...

Comment: Can you edit your question and put your example there as code?  I'm not seeing more than one consecutive space in your comment.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to handle tab characters too?  "Whitespace" isn't normally just "space" characters.

Comment: @Hightechrider: Actually, now you mention it... I would. Will edit question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about an extension method on String?  I passed in the tabLength to make the function more flexible.  I also added a separate method to return the whitespace length since one comment that that is what you were looking for.

```
public static string GetLeadingWhitespace(this string s, int tabLength = 4, bool trimToLowerTab = true)
{
  return new string(' ', s.GetLeadingWhitespaceLength());
}

public static int GetLeadingWhitespaceLength(this string s, int tabLength = 4, bool trimToLowerTab = true)
{
  if (s.Length < tabLength) return 0;

  int whiteSpaceCount = 0;

  while (Char.IsWhiteSpace(s[whiteSpaceCount])) whiteSpaceCount++;

  if (whiteSpaceCount < tabLength) return 0;

  if (trimToLowerTab)
  {
    whiteSpaceCount -= whiteSpaceCount % tabLength;
  }

  return whiteSpaceCount;
}
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks. I cant beleive i didnt think of making it an extension method!

Comment: Wouldn't this code throw an exception if you call GetLeadingWhitespaceLength() on a string with 5 spaces?

Comment: I don't have time to debug it right now, but I don't think that it will throw.  If you pass SSSSSX (where S == space), then the first "if" is not passed, so zero is not returned.  The while loop simply counts the leading spaces yielding, in this case, whiteSpaceCount = 5.  whiteSpaceCount (5) is not less than tabLength (4), so zero is not returned.  trimToLowerTab is true, so whiteSpaceCount is reduced by whiteSpaceCount (5) % tabLength (4) (1).  So, whiteSpaceCount is ultimately 4.

Comment: Martin means that it will throw because there is no bounds check on whiteSpaceCount, so if the string contains only spaces it will go out of bounds. (Proposed an edit to fix it.)

Comment: Add `whiteSpaceCount < s.Length && ` in the beginning of the while-loop to fix it. (Edit rejected.)

Answer (score 7):

I didn't run any performance tests but this is less code.

```
...

whitespace = line.Length - line.TrimStart(' ').Length;

...
```

Comment: Note:  You can remove the `' '` to get all whitespace and not just `' '`.

Comment: @rmx - Nevermind my earlier comments then.  :)  Austin's answer returns an integer.  If you want to convert that to actual whitespace you can do `return new string(' ', whitespace);`

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else looking to get the whitespace as a string, I personally found this to be simple and straightforward:

```
    public static string GetLeadingWhitespace(string str)
    {
        //Check if str is empty, since String.Replace() throws an exception when the first argument is an empty string
        if(str == String.Empty) {
            return String.Empty;
        }
        return str.Replace(str.TrimStart(), "");
    }
```

Just replace everything that's *not* the leading whitespace with an empty string. This will also work for any sort of whitespace - not just spaces. Thanks to @bobwki for pointing out an edge case where this failed - I've added a check for empty strings.

Comment: so... this causes a crash when str is empty:  Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: String cannot be of zero length. (Parameter 'oldValue')

Comment: @bobwki thanks for pointing that out! I've added a check for empty strings to avoid that edge case.

Comment: Nice and elegant!

Comment: @SimonElms thank you so much! That's very kind.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [Char.IsWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace.aspx) instead of comparing with `' '`, usually. Not all "spaces" are `' '`

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's nothing built in, but you can use a regular expression to do this if you're comfortable with them. This matches any whitespace at the beginning of the line:

```
public static string GetLeadingWhitespace(string line)
{
  return Regex.Match(line, @"^([\s]+)").Groups[1].Value;
}
```

NOTE: This would not perform as well as a simple loop. I would just go with your implementation.

Comment: Also: I'm ignoring the "nearest multiple of 4 part" as the original question claimed that it wasn't important.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing built in, but how about:

```
var result = line.TakeWhile(x => x == ' ');
if (trimToLowerTab)
    result = result.Skip(result.Count() % 4);
return new string(result.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Kirk's answer

```
var leadingWhiteSpace = line.TakeWhile(x => x == ' ');
leadingWhiteSpace = String.Join("", leadingWhiteSpace.ToArray());
```