# Tab Space on C Sharp

Tags: c#, .net, string, tabs

I have created a small program to write XML-Comment for Properties(which dont have customer attributes applied).

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Write XML-Comment for Properties(which dont have customer attributes applied).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">'*.cs' file along with full path to comment.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static bool WriteComment(string fileName)
    {
        List<string> code = new List<string>();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                code.Add(sr.ReadLine());
            }

            List<int> indexes = (from line in code
                                 where line.Contains("get")
                                 select code.IndexOf(line)).ToList();

            int count = 0;
            foreach (int i in indexes)
            {
                code.Insert((i + count++) - 2, getWhiteSpace(code[(i + count) - 3]) + "/// <summary>");
                code.Insert((i + count++) - 2, getWhiteSpace(code[(i + count) - 3]) + "/// Gets or Sets the " + getPropertyName(code[(i + count) - 3]));
                code.Insert((i + count++) - 2, getWhiteSpace(code[(i + count) - 3]) + "/// </summary>");
            }
        }

#if DEBUG
        foreach (string line in code)
            Console.WriteLine(line);
#else
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            foreach (string line in code)
                sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
#endif

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To retrive property name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="property">Property Name Line(line with visibiliy mode and return type ).</param>
    /// <returns>Property Name.</returns>
    public static string getPropertyName(string property)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(property.Substring(property.LastIndexOf(" ")), "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2").TrimStart();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get initial position of the property. So that XML-comment can be placed properly 
    /// at the top.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="codeLine">Property Line code.</param>
    /// <returns>Number of White Space.</returns>
    public static string getWhiteSpace(string codeLine)
    {
        string retStr = "";
        foreach (string s in codeLine.Split())
        {
            if (s != string.Empty) break;
            retStr += " ";
        }
        return retStr;
    }
```

As you can see on the method `getWhiteSpace` I'm checking for `Empty String` and it works well. But, if I apply `string.Empty` to `retStr` on loop...the returned value will be `string.Empty` only! This I can understand that concatenating the `string.Empty` will result `string.Empty` only.

Now my question is how `if (s != string.Empty)` is working and why `if (s != " ")` or `if (s != "\t")` is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on .NET 4.0, have a look at [**String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)

```
if(s != string.Empty) break;
if(s != "") break;
```

are essentially the same. 
this should tell you why

`if(s != " ") break;`

is not working. It is because `""` is not equal to `" "`.
the same is true for `"\t"`: it is not equal to either `" "` or `""`

---

Update:
I figure you're trying to get the number of whitespaces at the beginning of each line in order to correctly indent the auto generated comments.
I'd probably go about this as follows:

**EDIT: removed own code. Instead take a look here:**

[Get leading whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907807/get-leading-whitespace)

Comment: first off: I think your code does not compile, as you call to `String.Split()` without any method arguments. If you in fact use `Split(new char[] {' '})` the whitespaces will get thrown out of the returned array.

Comment: So you must be using extension methods. Anyway: What do you want to achieve? Are you trying to find out the number of whitespaces at the beginning of each line to get indentation correct?

Comment: No I'm not using any extension methods. I'm just calling `WriteComment` method with `SomeProgram.cs` file. Yes, I want the number of whitespaces at the beginning of each line to get correct indentation. However, the code is forking fine. Sorry...for my bad English!

Comment: The thing I wonder is...I'm saving the file with a long white space infront of my comment (i.e. by constructing `retStr` with spaceses). But when I read the same comment it becoming empty string instead of white space!

Comment: Thanks..you guided me to the answer. The problem was on `codeLine.Split()` where it is splitting string by `' '`. When I use the loop `foreach (char c in codeLine)` by checking for white space like `if (c != ' ')` it worked well.

Answer (score 2):

String.Empty is ""
If you want to check if string is "\t" or " " use
string.IsNullOrEmpty and string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace methods

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty` and `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` works fine! my question is not that. I wanted to know how exactly empty space is inserted on the document which I cant create.

Answer (score 0):

\t is for a tab space. Tab space is different from empty space. Tab space will have more than 1 empty space in it.

String.Empty and "" is same, except that 1 deciphers at run time and other at compile time.

Comment: Are you sure on second line? as far as I know `String.Empty` is `""` and not `" "`. If `String.Empty` is `" "`, then concatenating them should work right?

Comment: Is it not "" i wrote above? Damn! Sorry folks.